# Delete single item in SQL array PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-delete

This has been driving me crazy: 
If I have an entry in a SQL db as such: [1,2,3,4]

How can I delete a single item in the array?

```
mysqli_query = ("DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$id'... (something to specify the item here)");??
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?  It basically looks correct, assuming you are actually executing it.

Comment: If it's a CSV list in a column, and you just want to evict an entry in there, your application logic is responsible for updating it. -- If you wanted to DELETE *a row* which contains one of the numeric ids, then `FIND_IN_SET` would do.

Comment: For example, in my 'items' column, I have [1,2,3,4] and I want to delete just ',3' (the comma as well) - I'm at a loss as to how to do it. 
I will try FIND_IN_SET now.

Comment: That won't help with updating the CSV list. It's just for searching. Relational databases aren't designed to cope with structured data *within columns*. You have to query the entry, then issue an UPDATE for it.

Comment: Ahhhh, really? 
Thank you... I can do that.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't quite work out. Let me give you a visual: 
I have a table with 3 colums: 
user_id,
pid_like,
pid_dislike, 
the latter 2 are arrays. If I add a number to 'pid_like' and it's already in pid_dislike, I need to delete that item from pid_dislike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, adjust it as needed of course.

```
$string = cell date to here;

$new_string = str_replace('replace', 'with', $string);

echo "{$string}<br>{$new_string}";

// commented until new strings visually compared.
#mysqli_query("update table set `items` = {$new_string} WHERE `id` = {$id}");
```

I prefer to use braces around variables, its just a preference and i dont normally use html inside php but for a single break line it seems pointless to skip out and back into php.

Comment: That would be fine for inputting, but if I already have a column entry = [1,2,3,4] how do I remove just ,3?
Also, I can't say UPDATE table SET 'items' = '1,2,4' WHERE, etc... because it's too large for me to declare all the values. 
if I could do ($items -$itemIdontWant); that would be amazing.

Comment: Simply pull the cell data from the table, now you will have it in a string. If you are absolutely certain that you will not match anything else. str_replace() will do what you need. I would run a test first, echo both strings, the original and the modified string and check the integrity of your new date, once confirmed you can add an update query to commit the modification.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: str_replace works great! But it leaves a trailing comma ;( I will work with it. Thank you!

Comment: if you need rid off the comma, add i into the part that says replace. EG "1,2,3,4" where i have put replace in my code to remove 3 from the string with its comma i would put "3,"

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was nonsense, STR_REPLACE is the ticket. Here is the complete like/dislike code:

```
//LIKE FIELD  
    if(isset($_POST['like'.$id])) { 
    if (!in_array("$id", $like_explode)){
    if (!in_array("$id", $dislike_explode)){
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like=CONCAT(pid_like,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");  
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes+1) WHERE id='$id'"); 
    }   
    else 
    { 
    $new_dislike_string = str_replace(",$id", '', $dislike_string);
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike='$new_dislike_string' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like=CONCAT(pid_like,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes+1) WHERE id='$id'"); 
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET dislikes=(dislikes-1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    }  
    } 
//DISLIKE FIELD         
    if(isset($_POST['dislike'.$id])) { 
    if (!in_array("$id", $dislike_explode)){
    if (!in_array("$id", $like_explode)){
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike=CONCAT(pid_dislike,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");  
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(dislikes+1) WHERE id='$id'"); 
    }   
    else 
    { 
    $new_like_string = str_replace(",$id", '', $like_string);
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_like='$new_like_string' WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE likes SET pid_dislike=CONCAT(pid_dislike,',$id') WHERE user_id='$user_id'");
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET dislikes=(dislikes+1) WHERE id='$id'"); 
    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE comments SET likes=(likes-1) WHERE id='$id'");
    }
    }  
    }    
//LIKE-DISLIKE FIELD END
```

Thanks a million, Chris!

P.S. Only sacrifice is beginning default value of the pid_like/dislike fields as '0' or else doing some nasty bit of trimming to get rid of the first ','